# How to check the length of a JPA query parameter if it is a list?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
 @Query("Select DISTINCT answer from Answer answer " +
        "WHERE ( answer.user = :user or (:user is null)) " +
        "AND ( answer.quiz in :quizzes or (:quizzes is null))"
)
public Page<Answer> multiParam(Quiz[] quizzes, User user, Pageable pageable);
```

This query works as long as quizzes is provided.

User however is optional.

The problem is that when quizzes the parameter is missing, the is null check will fail with this error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Encountered array-valued parameter binding, but was expecting [com.quiz.models.Quiz (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Encountered array-valued parameter binding, but was expecting [com.quiz.models.Quiz (n/a)
```

I want to find a way to make Quizzes the parameter as optional.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following :

```
 @Query("Select DISTINCT answer from Answer answer " +
        "WHERE ( answer.user = :user or (:user is null)) " +
        "AND (COALASCE(:quizzes,null) IS NULL OR answer.quiz in :quizzes))"
public Page<Answer> multiParam(List<Quiz> quizzes, User user, Pageable pageable);
```

COALASCE returns the first non null value , which in this case would return null when quizzes is null.

Not sure if this would work with Array type or not.

A native solution from JPA is still pending : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/622

Comment: Tried it, it got worse. Now it gives "did not match expected type" error even when quizzes is supplied.

Comment: Coalesce is supported since JPA 2.0 ,so if you are above it , that is not the issue.Are you leveraging Arrays or List ? 
Can you also provide the complete error , wanna check at which point it is failing , "in" or "coalasce"